# How to generate similar hash password using sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, md5

Cryptography algorithm is md5.

In C#, I am using following code to generate password:-

```
private MD5 _md5;
var plain = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes('admin');
var hashed = _md5.ComputeHash(plain);
var shashed = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(hashed);
Console.Write(shashed);
```

Result is: `!#/)zW¥§C‰JJ€Ã`

When I use SQL server code to generate password:-

```
DECLARE @HashThis varchar(100);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(varchar(100),'admin');
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', @HashThis);
GO
```

Result is: `0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3`

I am using the same algorithm. How can I generate same hash value in SQL Server?

Comment: MD5 is not secure, especially without salt.  You should use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: What you see in SQL is the Hex representation where as your C# code is writing the byte values out to the Console and you will get the representation in the Font of those byte values. 
And storing passwords in hash in SQL is common practice and secure enough because you want to compare the calculated hashed value from a password during login. If you use encryption instead then you open up for people being able to decrypt the password, where as a hashed value has to be brute-forced

Comment: And MD5 is **not** cryptography - it's hashing.

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code and the SQL code are both computing the same hash value, but SQL is formatting the result as a hex string while your C# code is attempting to cast the bytes of the hash value directly to ASCII characters (which they are not).  To get the same result in C# you could use the BitConverter class:

```
var shashed = "0x" + System.BitConverter.ToString(hashed).Replace("-", "");
```

Output:

```
0x21232F297A57A5A743894A0E4A801FC3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the result against a characterset table;

In most charactersets, 0x21 is !, 0x23 is #, etc.